# Автоперенос кнопок в таблице (html)

Tags: html

Всем привет! Только сейчас зарегистрировался на нашем форуме и задаю вопрос почти сразу) Я чайник и в программирование пытаюсь только-только влезть.
Выполняя д/з я делал сайт и при вставке одного текста всё хорошо(кнопки в 1 ряд), но если я вставлю другой текст, то кнопки смещаются в два ряда.
(прошу прощение за имхо-код) [image: 1]
[image: 2]

```html
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
<title>Главная</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor=white text=black>
<table border=1  align=center>
<tr align=center>
<td align=center valign=top>
</table>
<table border=1 >
<tr>
<td >
<IMG src=./pic/logotip.png border=0  height=70 alt="Логотип" title="Веселый зоопарк"align=left hspace=5 vspace=5>
</td>
<td> <h1>Компьютерные сети</h1> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td> Главная | <a href=lev.html>Лев</a> | <a href=tigr.html>Тигр</a> | <a href=slon.html>Слон</a>   | <a href=avtor.html>Автор</a> |  <a href=link.html>Ссылки</a> |
</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td valign=top>
<img src=./pic/index_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Главная">
 <a href=lev.html>
 <img src=./pic/lev_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Лев" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/lev_on.png'"onmouseout="this.src='pic/lev_of.png'"></a> 
 <a href=tigr.html>
 <img src=./pic/tigr_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Тигр" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/tigr_on.png'"onmouseout="this.src='pic/tigr_of.png'"></a> 
<a href=slon.html>
 <img src=./pic/slon_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Слон" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/slon_on.png'"onmouseout="this.src='pic/slon_of.png'"></a> 
<a href=avtor.html>
 <img src=./pic/avtor_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Автор" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/avtor_on.png'"onmouseout="this.src='pic/avtor_of.png'"></a>     
  <a href=link.html>
 <img src=./pic/link_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Ссылки" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/link_on.png'"onmouseout="this.src='pic/link_of.png'"></a>  
</td>
</td>
<td valign=top>
  <h2><center> Главная </h2>
<img src="./pic/zoo.jpg" border=0 hspace=15 vspace=15 alt="Зоопарк" title="Зоопарк" align=right>
 На этом сайте вы можите узнать о необычных  представителях фауны.</center>  
<p>    Одна из важных и целенаправленных сторон деятельности зоопарка — содержание диких животных для демонстрации их городскому населению и просветительская деятельность по охране природы и животного мира, развивая в людях представление о том, что они являются частью мира живой природы и что ответственность за сохранение этого мира должна гармонично войти в их повседневную жизнь; изучение биологии и психологии своих коллекций, а также сохранение видов и их воспроизводство с последующей реинтродукцией в естественные местообитания, помогающие восстановить и сохранить вымирающих представителей животного мира в дикой природе. Участие в различных международных программах по сохранению и восстановлению исчезающих видов помогло избежать утери от вымирания в природной среде популяций зубров и куланов, некоторых представителей птиц, земноводных и пресмыкающихся.
 </td>
 <tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td> Главная |<a href=lev.html>Лев </a>| <a href=tigr.html>Тигр</a> | <a href=slon.html>Слон</a> | <a href=avtor.html>Автор</a> |  <a href=link.html>Ссылки</a> |
</td>
 </tr>   
 <tr><td></td>
 <td>&copy;2015 Дизайн - Ершов Павел.
<a href=23persh@gmail.com>23persh@gmail.com</a>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
  <title>Главная</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor=white text=black>
  <table border=1 align=center>
    <tr align=center>
      <td align=center valign=top>
  </table>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <IMG src=./pic/logotip.png border=0 height=70 alt="Логотип" title="Веселый зоопарк" align=left hspace=5 vspace=5>
      </td>
      <td>
        <h1>Компьютерные сети</h1> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Главная | <a href=lev.html>Лев</a> | <a href=tigr.html>Тигр</a> | <a href=slon.html>Слон</a> | <a href=avtor.html>Автор</a> | <a href=link.html>Ссылки</a> |
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign=top>
        <img src=./pic/index_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Главная">
        <a href=lev.html>
          <img src=./pic/lev_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Лев" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/lev_on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='pic/lev_of.png'">
        </a>
        <a href=tigr.html>
          <img src=./pic/tigr_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Тигр" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/tigr_on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='pic/tigr_of.png'">
        </a>
        <a href=slon.html>
          <img src=./pic/slon_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Слон" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/slon_on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='pic/slon_of.png'">
        </a>
        <a href=avtor.html>
          <img src=./pic/avtor_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Автор" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/avtor_on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='pic/avtor_of.png'">
        </a>
        <a href=link.html>
          <img src=./pic/link_of.png width=130 height=40 border=0 alt="Ссылки" style="cursor:hand" onmouseover="this.src='pic/link_on.png'" onmouseout="this.src='pic/link_of.png'">
        </a>
      </td>
      </td>
      <td valign=top>
        <h2><center> Главная </h2>
        На этом сайте вы можите узнать о необычных представителях фауны.</center>
        <p>Интернет — всемирная система объединённых компьютерных сетей для хранения и передачи информации. Часто упоминается как Всемирная сеть и Глобальная сеть, а также просто Сеть. Построена на базе стека протоколов TCP/IP. На основе интернета работает
          Всемирная паутина (World Wide Web, WWW) и множество других систем передачи данных. К 30 июня 2012 года число пользователей, регулярно использующих интернет, составило более чем 2,4 млрд человек, более трети населения Земли пользовалось услугами
          интернета.
      </td>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Главная |<a href=lev.html>Лев </a>| <a href=tigr.html>Тигр</a> | <a href=slon.html>Слон</a> | <a href=avtor.html>Автор</a> | <a href=link.html>Ссылки</a> |
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>&copy;2015 Дизайн - Ершов Павел.
          <a href=23persh@gmail.com>23persh@gmail.com</a>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: поставьте фиксированную ширину на колонку таблицы, вкоторой у Вас кнопки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задай ширину ячеек < td width="..." >

В тех ячейках, в которых располагаются кнопки, задай одну ширину (например, 300px), а в тех, в которых текст - другую (например, 1000px). Ширину можно задавать в процентах.

Обрати внимание, что у ячеек, которые располагаются в одном столбце, ширина должна быть одинаковая.

И проверь, чтобы каждый тег был закрыт, а то у тебя

< td > & copy;2015 Дизайн - Ершов Павел....

не закрыт. < /td>